# How to make a simple top navigation bar wrap gracefully at all screen dimensions with only CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to do something that should be simple but is apparently not so.  I just want to make a simple single line navigation bar using a list tag.   Thats fine, I can do it.  The problem is making it wrap gracefully and still keep the same layout when it needs to appear over multiple rows due to not enough horizontal browser space.

As I say, I'm using a list tag and I have the ride side border of each LI item with a visible vertical line to make the divider appear.  The final item I am not shwoing that with a last-child pseudo class.  Its important that the far left and right buttons DON'T have vertical borders.   This is clear in the top image.

The UL tag itself also has a top/bottom border line visible and in the first demo in the image you can see this clearly.

So now what happens when the menu bar wraps... well there there are 2 key problems...

1) The main issue is that when the menu wraps I can't think of a way to make the new MIDDLE horizontal line appear [shown in red in the 2nd image]

2) Multiple list items now don't need a right side border value.  In the example 2 list items don't need a right side border.   This could grow to 3 though for some screen displays.

Does anyone have any ideas for resolving this?

Note that I am trying to make the menu wrap naturally, not at fixed pixel break points as its so unreliable for something like this with different pixel density screens and font zooms in certain browsers.

[image: Demo of how the menu looks when with enough room and how it would wrap with items staying centered]

Comment: Please provide the code you have in the question itself if you're looking get it corrected.

Comment: As for the solution, you can either use very specific media queries if the number of elements is set or use JavaScript if it is not